# VideoJS 5 plugin add button

Tags: plugins, video.js

I looked everywhere on the internet but I couldn't find any clear documentation or some examples to create my verySimplePlugin for videoJS 5 (Since it uses ES6).

I just want to add a button next to the big play button... Can someone help me?

Thanks...

PS: I'm using it in angularJS but I guess this can not a problem

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can add download button to the end of control bar without any plugins or other complicated code:

```
var vjsButtonComponent = videojs.getComponent('Button');
videojs.registerComponent('DownloadButton', videojs.extend(vjsButtonComponent, {
    constructor: function () {
        vjsButtonComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    handleClick: function () {
        document.location = '/path/to/your/video.mp4'; //< there are many variants here so it is up to you how to get video url
    },
    buildCSSClass: function () {
        return 'vjs-control vjs-download-button';
    },
    createControlTextEl: function (button) {
        return $(button).html($('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>').attr('title', 'Download'));
    }
}));

videojs(
    'player-id',
    {fluid: true},
    function () {
        this.getChild('controlBar').addChild('DownloadButton', {});
    }
);
```

I used 'glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt' icon and a title for it so it fits to the player control bar styling.

How it works:

1. We registering a new component called 'DownloadButton' that extends built-in 'Button' component of video.js lib
2. In constructor we're calling constructor of the 'Button' component (it is quite complicated for me to understand it 100% but it is similar as calling parent::__construct() in php)
3. buildCSSClass - set button classes ('vjs-control' is must have!)
4. createControlTextEl - adds content to the button (in this case - an icon and title for it)
5. handleClick - does something when user presses this button
6. After player was initialized we're adding 'DownloadButton' to 'controlBar'

Note: there also should be a way to place your button anywhere within 'controlBar' but I haven't figured out how because download button is ok in the end of the control bar

Comment: Nice concept and the code to create download button DOES work. However, since no HTML is shown, it is very time-consuming to figure that part out (e.g glyph icon). Another big drawback is that when you click on the button, the video downloads into a new browser tab, which isn't obvious, because the new tab isn't an adjacent tab, so the original videojs viewer containing the download button disappears (The back-button in browser is needed to get back.)  And there seems to be no way to change where it downloads to..  So, overall, this code doesn't seem practical.  But,I LIKE no plugin needed !

Answer (score 1):

This is how I created a simple button plugin for videojs 5:

```
(function() {
var vsComponent = videojs.getComponent('Button');

// Create the button
videojs.SampleButton = videojs.extend(vsComponent, {
    constructor: function() {
        vsComponent.call(this, videojs, null);
    }
});

// Set the text for the button
videojs.SampleButton.prototype.buttonText = 'Mute Icon';

// These are the defaults for this class.
videojs.SampleButton.prototype.options_ = {};

// videojs.Button uses this function to build the class name.
videojs.SampleButton.prototype.buildCSSClass = function() {
    // Add our className to the returned className
    return 'vjs-mute-button ' + vsComponent.prototype.buildCSSClass.call(this);
};

// videojs.Button already sets up the onclick event handler, we just need to overwrite the function
videojs.SampleButton.prototype.handleClick = function( e ) {
    // Add specific click actions here.
    console.log('clicked');
};

videojs.SampleButton.prototype.createEl = function(type, properties, attributes) {
    return videojs.createEl('button', {}, {class: 'vjs-mute-btn'});
};

var pluginFn = function(options) {
    var SampleButton  = new videojs.SampleButton(this, options);
    this.addChild(SampleButton);

    return SampleButton;
};

videojs.plugin('sampleButton', pluginFn);
})();
```

You can use it this way:

```
var properties = { "plugins": { "muteBtn": {} } }

var player = videojs('really-cool-video', properties , function() { //do something cool here });
```

Or this way:

```
player.sampleButton()
```